# How to download a pdf file using ExtJS 4.2.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am developing a personal web site and i have a pdf in my resources.

I need a button with the handler to save pdf file in browser.
My application only have client side.

How i can download pdf file in browser with Extjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just this:

```
window.open("your_pdf_url.pdf", "_blank")
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: this will open pdf at new window. I want to make download at the button click

Answer (score 3):

The following code used to download the pdf using extjs. Add the following code should be invoked for button action. This downloads the file directly insteadof opening in new tab.
Make sure that server side has

**Server side**

In the server side once you generate the report, you should set the following headers

**header.set("application/pdf");**

**header.set("Content-disposition: inline; filename=Test.pdf");**

**Client Side**
**1. Add the button in the view**

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Print PDF',
    cls: 'printPdfBtn',
    listeners: {
        click: 'printReport'
        //click: 'openReport'
    }
}
```

**2. Add the listener method in controller.**

Option:1 Use hidden iframe to download the pdf file.

use an iframe like this:

```
/**
 * prints the file
 */
printReport: function () {
    var url = 'downloadURL';
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        autoAbort: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.status == 204) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Empty Report', 'There is no data');
            } else if(result.status == 200) {
                Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), {
                    tag:          'iframe',
                    frameBorder:  0,
                    width:        0,
                    height:       0,
                    css:          'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
                    src:          url
                });
            }
        },
        failure: function() {
            // failure action
        }
    });
}
```

Copied the answer from [extjs forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153253-How-to-download-a-file-using-Ext.Ajax-using-a-POST-call)

The following code used to download the file using extjs. Add the following code to method and invoke this for button action. PDF will be opened in new tab.

option:2 Open pdf in tab.
If you want to open the file in new tab

```
    /**
 * open file in tab
 */
openReport: function () {
    var url = 'downloadURL';
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        autoAbort: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.status == 204) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Empty Report', 'There is no data');
            } else if(result.status == 200) {
                var win = window.open('', '_blank');
                win.location = url;
                win.focus();
            }
        },
        failure: function() {
            // failure action
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Ext JS. Just open a new window with the path to the PDF file.

Comment: I want to save pdf not to open in a new window.

Comment: I could certainly be wrong, but without using the server to set headers, I think you're only option is to open the file and allow the user to save the file themselves.